# The file '/mypage.aspx' has not been pre-compiled, and cannot be requested

Tags: asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2005, c#-2.0

I have a VS 2005 web site that I publish using "Publish Web Site", and I clear all the three checkboxes. I modify the `mypage.aspx` file and publish web site.

Then, I replace that file with the old one and I get this error:

> The file '/mypage.aspx' has not been pre-compiled, and cannot be requested.

How can I replace that file?

Answer (score 0):

This error appears also when a reference is specified in your web.config file and deployment folder/site does not contain these dlls (or the specific version you specified in the web.config) installed in the system (GAC) or bin folder does not contain them.

Example:

```
<add assembly="Namespace.BlaBla, Version=1.2.3.4, Culture=neutral,
   PublicKeyToken=7aff3896eb354e31"/>
```

If you deploy version 1.2.3.5 of that DLL you'll get the (misleading) error message.

Answer (score -2):

May be in server c drive is out of space